# ASP.NET MVC 3 Delete Http Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've been looking around the web for how to do just a delete HttpPost missing out the get, i've read that it is safer to do a post instead of a Get, so that is what i want to do.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(Guid id)
    {

        var member = GetSelectedMember(id);

        _repository.DeleteEntity(member);

        TempData["message"] = String.Format("Blog {0} has been deleted!", member.Name);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

That is my Post Method.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Member", FormMethod.Post, new { id = item.ID }))
{
    <input type="image" src="Content/delete.png" />
}
```

That is my Razor view.

Below is the error i get

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Delete(System.Guid)' in 'GenericSaving.Controllers.MemberController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

So, I can't break on the method because it pings the error before then, my first guess is that it isn't passing the Guid ID to the parameter. So based on my form what is going wrong?

I've thought that maybe as a solution i could put it in a hidden field on the form? How would I collect the contents of this field in the post method?

Comment: Put a break on `Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Member", FormMethod.Post, new { id = item.ID }` and see what `item.ID` holds when assigning it to the querystring object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are using wrong overload method for beginForm. Check [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492933%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for correct usage. Use like this:

```
Html.BeginForm("action","controller", new { Id = item.ID}, FormMethod.Post);
```

OR

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Member", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Hidden("id", item.ID)
    <input type="image" src="Content/delete.png" />
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I guess your answering my solution, so wheres the second bit, and maybe some explanations?

Comment: Is it really neccessary to use a hidden field when the querystring already holds the value?? `new { id = item.ID }`

Comment: I'll accept this answer in 9 minutes, when it allows me to :)

Comment: So, do you actually need to state that this form posts? and did my form post the int of enum Post?